# Can I Recover Lost Emails on iPad After Changing Password?

Tags: ipad, email

Short Story: I recently lost all my sent emails (POP3) on my iPad when I migrated my server and password.  The domain name and username did not change.  Is there *any* way to recover those sent emails?

Longer Story: My web host just migrated to a new system.  They advised me my account might not work.  When my email went down, I moved everything to my secondary server.

I didn't change my email address, but I had to change my password for email on this secondary server, because of its password rules. At this point, all my emails, inbox and sent, were still on my iPad.

When I updated the password on my iPad so it would download emails from the new server, everything else disappeared.  All my old inbox messages, and all my sent emails.

I can recover my Inbox from archives on the old server, but it doesn't have my sent emails. Support tells me those were only local.

I'm hoping there's some way to recover those.

Thanks for your advice.

Alec

Comment: Any backups with iCloud or iTunes?

Comment: No, that's a different sad story.  My iMac crashed (both boot drive and Time Capsule).  However, I did finally solve this problem.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being told on the Apple Discussion boards that this can't be done, I found a solution.

I re-entered all the original log in information into the account details.  It took a bit to get them to stick, because iPad kept trying to verify the account, which it couldn't do, because the legacy server wasn't responding, but I finally got it.  Once the I had the original credentials entered, all the original Inbox and Sent emails were back.

One important key: Although I didn't change my email *address*, the new server did require a different username syntax.  The old username was just "name" while the new username was "name@mydomain.com".  That little change is what caused iPad to decide it was an entirely different account.